# Magento 1.7.0.2 : Creating a Website fails (Redis backend cache error)

Tags: magento-1.7, cache, backend, redis

I'm having an issue, just trying to create a new website.
I'm entering the information in System / Manage stores / Create Website.

First, It fails with a `fatal Error 512 Mo exhausted ...`

I increased memory in php.ini to 1024M and now it fails with a message :

An error occurred while saving. Please review the error log.

In exception.log I get this :

`Exception message: Error cleaning cache by mode matchingAnyTag: read error on connection
Trace: #0 ...../Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php(671): Zend_Cache::throwException('Error cleaning ...', Object(CredisException))`

So .... I'm a bit confused, can't find anything anywhere about this issue.

I tried editing the file, checking where the problem may come from but still no clue.

Thanks for any lead.

**EDIT** : ok so ... Changing the read_timeout value in /app/etc/mylocalfile.xml is actually delaying the exception, so the exception does seem to come from redis reading timing out...

**Question is : Why the hell is the website creation taking sooooo long ?**

Retrying with a 200sec timeout (100 sec just failed)

Answer (score 2):

Well ... I guess my redis database was corrupted or something.

> redis-cli
>   then
>   flushall

And it's smooth again now.

Comment: or `echo flushall | redis-cli`  :)

Comment: you can just use `redis-cli flushall`. No need to open the cli prompt or echo into it.